# How to update nested JSON array in scala

Tags: json, scala, playframework

I'm a newbie to scala/play and I've been trying to update (add a new id to) the `query` array in the `sections[1]` of the JSON but I've had no success traversing the JSON as I have little knowledge of transformers and how to use it.

```
  "definitions": [
    {
      "sections": [
        {
          "priority": 1,
          "content": {
            "title": "Driver",
            "links": [
              {
                "url": "https://blabla.com",
                "text": "See all"
              }
            ]
          },
          "SearchQuery": {
            "options": {
              "aggregate": true,
              "size": 20,
            },
            "query": "{\"id\":{\"include\":[\"0wxZ4Nr2\", \"0wxZbNr2\", \"6WZOPMw1\"}}"
          }
        },
        {
          "priority": 2,
          "content": {
            "title": "Deliver",
            "links": [
              {
                "url": "https://blabla.com",
                "text": "See all"
              }
            ]
          },
          "SearchQuery": {
            "options": {
              "aggregate": true,
              "size": 20,
            },
            "query": "{\"id\":{\"include\":[\"2W12Q2wq\", \"Nwq09lW3\", \"QweNN2d9\"]}}"
          }
        }
  ]
}
```

Any suggestions on how I can achieve this. My goal is to put values inside the specific fields of JSON array. I am using play JSON library throughout my application?

Comment: It would be good if you could add the code snippet or whatever you have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you noticed if you use PlayJSON you can use [Json Transformers](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaJsonTransformers#JSON-coast-to-coast-design)

Updating a field would work like this:

```
val queryUpdater = (__ \ "definitions" \ 1 \ "SearchQuery" \ "query").json.update(
  of[JsString].map {
    case JsString(value) =>
      val newValue: String = ... // calculate new value
      JsString(newValue)
  }
)

json.transform(queryUpdater)
```

If you needed to update all queries it would be more like:

```
val updateQuery = (__ \ "SearchQuery" \ "query").json.update(
  of[JsString].map {
    case JsString(value) =>
      val newValue: String = ... // calculate new value
      JsString(newValue)
  }
)

val updateQueries = (__ \ "definitions").json.update(
  of[JsArray].map {
    case JsArray(arr) =>
      JsArray(arr.map(_.transform(updateQuery)))
  }
)

json.transform(updateQueries)
```